# Why does IE 8 return undefined for JSON response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have been working on a laravel 5 app which works well in all major browser except IE 9 and below. In one of my controllers, I have an ajax response like below:

```
if ($validation->fails())
{
  return response()->json($validation->errors()->all(), 400);
}
```

In my JS, I have the sample code below:

```
var options = {
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
        success: showResponse,  // post-submit callback
        uploadProgress: OnProgress, //upload progress callback
        error: function(data){
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            // Render errors with JS
            alert(errors);
            $.each(errors, function(index, value)
            {
               if (value.length != 0)
               {
                    $("#cv_msg").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
               }
            });
            $("#cv_msg").show();
        },
        data: queryString,
        url:  document_form.attr('action'),
        type:      'post',
        dataType:  'json'
    };

    // attach handler to form's submit event
    document_form.ajaxSubmit(options);
```

In Chrome and Firefox, `alert(errors)` displays the validation errors while IE is undefined. What exactly can be the problem here?

Comment: Check the request in the network console - you'll get much more information about the error.

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.xx @Tushar. XP is being used by many in my area.